# GetMapping method is not working in other packages

Tags: spring-boot

I wrote a simple API using Spring Boot. But GetMapping annotation isn't working in other packages and everytime I have tried got 404 error.
When I used this GetMapping annotation in the main method it works.

I use ComponentScan and most of the solution that are existed on google but error is still happening. I have no idea what to do.

This is my code of main method.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.demo.controller")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is the controller class which is located in controller folder.

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

[Project Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxMLr.png)

I wrote the GetMapping method like this, it works.

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

This is the log.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.3)

2023-02-24T19:49:53.726+06:30  INFO 65555 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 19.0.2 with PID 65555 (/home/bbee/Personal Projects/demo/target/classes started by bbee in /home/bbee/Personal Projects/demo)
2023-02-24T19:49:53.732+06:30  INFO 65555 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-02-24T19:49:54.401+06:30  INFO 65555 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-02-24T19:49:54.408+06:30  INFO 65555 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-02-24T19:49:54.408+06:30  INFO 65555 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-02-24T19:49:54.457+06:30  INFO 65555 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-02-24T19:49:54.458+06:30  INFO 65555 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 668 ms
2023-02-24T19:49:54.743+06:30  INFO 65555 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-02-24T19:49:54.753+06:30  INFO 65555 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.342 seconds (process running for 1.644)
2023-02-24T19:50:01.924+06:30  INFO 65555 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-02-24T19:50:01.924+06:30  INFO 65555 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-02-24T19:50:01.925+06:30  INFO 65555 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

This is my porm.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.demo.controller")`

or change the scan path to application default `com.example.demo`.

try and let me known it works or not.

Comment: It doesn't still work.

Comment: enable debug logging , run and call api again , let’s see more infos